# How to get to the odata service of the list in SharePoint 2010

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, odata

If my list resides here:

```
 http://sharepoint2010m/Lists/VideoPlayerData/AllItems.aspx
```

How do I get actual items through the o-data service?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your REST endpoint would be: `http://sharepoint2010m/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/VideoPlayerData`

In your example, your List lives in the root. However, if you need to get to a List that lives deeper down, you tack on the `_vti_bin` after the last site in your URL.

For example, to access a List at:
`http://sharepoint2010m/MySite/MySubSite/Lists/MyList/AllItems.aspx`,

you'd ask for:

`http://sharepoint2010m/MySite/MySubSite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/MyList`

Microsoft also has a helpful article called [Using the REST Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx) you might want to check out.